# Fluent bind not working as expected

Tags: mvvmcross

Suppose I am binding using

```
bs.Bind(y)
  .For(v => v.Visibility)
  .To("Failures['TaxPercent'].Length")
  .WithConversion("Visibility")
  .WithFallback(false);
```

Where `Failures` is a dictionary which would contain the property name (e.g. `TaxPercent`) if, and only if, the property fails validation.
Therefore `Failure['TaxPercent']` returns the validation failure message (e.g value missing).

I want to have an expandable textview in Android which is visible only when the error is detected. I used the above code and it is not working. The fallback value does not trigger when `Failure['TaxPercent']` does not exist in the dictionary.

How do I get an expandable/collapsible textview based on the validation result using a dictionary in the viewmodel??? I would really like to use a dictionary because that would save me from creating IsErrorVisible for each property.

Oddly enough, using a dictionary works for retrieving the error message though, but not for visibility! In other words, this is working great

```
bs.Bind(y)
.For(v => v.Text)
.To("Failures['TaxPercent']");
```

Also, any reason why I cannot concatenate the binding, meaning can I do this???

```
bs.Bind(y)
  .For(v => v.Text)
  .To("Failures['TaxPercent']")
  .For(v => v.Visibility)
  .To("Failures['TaxPercent'].Length")
  .WithConversion("Visibility")
  .WithFallback(false);
```

EDIT

The error msg in the log is
MvxBind:Error:168.86 Problem seen during binding execution for binding Visibility for Failures['TaxPercent'].Length - problem ArgumentException: The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dictionary doesn't contain an entry for 'TaxPercent' then the expression `Failures['TaxPercent'].Length` will not evaluate (an exception will be throw) so `UnsetValue` will be used.

In the case of `UnsetValue`, the ValueConverter will not be called, and the Fallback will be used. This is the same pattern as in Wpf - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For your particular situation, it looks like you could either:

- change the Fallback to the correct value for the platform instead of to a boolean value (the question didn't specify which platform(s) you are using)
- create a new Visibility ValueConverter that takes `Failures` as its binding source and `'TaxPercent'` as its parameter
- remove the `.Length` from your binding expression - just test on the existence of the entry.
- you could switch to free text binding expressions - then you could do more complicated binding statements, including nested bindings, multiple value converters, multiple fallback values, ...

For this particular case, I would just drop the `.Length`

For "any reason why I cannot concatenate", that won't work as the return type of `Bind` is a single Fluent binding entry - not a Fluent binding set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am developing on android, and I did not know the fallback value should be using Gone/Visible. I thought it should be true/false.